# Put the cardview inside the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, cardview

I made a tab menu using several fragments. And I'm going to put a cardview in each of the Fragment.
I tried Googling, but all I had to do was put a cardview in activity.

I'd like to put a cardview in the Fragment, and then I'd like to implement initiation of a predefined set activity when I click on the card.

How can I do?

- I referred to https://www.codingdemos.com/android-tablayout-example-viewpager to tab menu.
- I attach my fragment layout(xml file) code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.aeyoung.csw.CommunityFragment">

  <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.aeyoung.csw.CommunityFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

- Also I add fragment code(java file)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommunityFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Create parameter
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_community);

        // initialize parameter "productList"
        setInitialData();

        //Find RecyclerView from fragment_community.xml
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create LinearLayoutManager and set it to RecyclerView
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        //Create MyAdapter object with the parameters and set to RecyclerView
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, productList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    private void setInitialData() {
        productList.add(new Product("text1", "text1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text2", "text2", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text3", "text3", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text4", "text4", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text5", "text5", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text6", "text6", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text7", "text7", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text8", "text8", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text9", "text9", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        productList.add(new Product("text10", "text10", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    }
}
```

PageAdapter.java code

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by abdalla on 2/18/18.
 */

public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MajorFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FresherFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CommunityFragment();
            case 3:
                return new SettingsFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

And the following error occurs when building.
"error: incompatible types: CommunityFragment cannot be converted to Fragment"

Comment: And there is no difference. Inflate the layout with the card and set the onClickListener on it.

Comment: what is your problem now? you can do both ... put cardView even in the activity and in the fragment..!

Comment: @MasoudDarzi I'm trying cardview in many times, but that is not working. I found one site, and I reffered to [this site](https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial). But  not working too.

Comment: @JeongGaon Add your codes to the question

Comment: @SamanSalehi I added a code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the error is telling you `"error: incompatible types: CommunityFragment cannot be converted to Fragment"` 
you CommunityFragment extends `AppCompatActivity` and it's not a fragment.

Comment: So it didn't work. But it still doesn't work and the same error occurs. Is that a problem with the Fragment layout?

Comment: I must check the code if you are getting error again. so if it's possible for you upload the code again or show us the error

Comment: The code you uploaded is working. Maybe there was an error because there was a build cache left. Thank you.